# How to mock React Ag Grid events (like onSelectionChanged) in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have AgGridReact which has an onSelectionChanged event for which I am trying to write unit test case . Below is my Ag grid

```
<div className="ag-theme-material list-grid">
<AgGridReact
          ref={gridRef}
          rowData={rowData}
          columnDefs={columnDefs}
          defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
          rowSelection={'multiple'}
          onSelectionChanged={onselectionchange}
          animateRows={true}
          suppressRowClickSelection={true}
></AgGridReact>
</div>
```

And below is how I have mocked the Ag grid component which also has an input type checkbox on click of which the onSelectionChanged method will be called for which I need to write test case, I am facing issue of mocking this event

```
jest.mock('ag-grid-react', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('ag-grid-react'),
  AgGridReact: (props: any) => (
    <table>
      <th>
        {props.columnDefs.map(({ field }: any) => (
          <td key={field}>{field}</td>
        ))}
      </th>

      <tbody data-testid="table-body">
        {props.rowData.map((data: any) => (
          <tr data-testid="table-row">
            <input type='checkbox' data-testid="checkbox-row" onClick={() => {}}/>
            {props.columnDefs.map(({ field , cellRenderer : CellRenderer }: any) => (
              <td key={field}>{data[field]}
              {CellRenderer && <CellRenderer />}
              </td>
            ))}
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  ),
}));
```

And below is the onselectionchange which is being called through onSelectionChanged

```
const onselectionchange = (event: SelectionChangedEvent) => {}
```

I would like to know how to mock this event.